# Why iterators are incompatible?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have following class:

```
class Manifest {
public:
    Manifest(void);
    ~Manifest(void);

    std::vector<ManifestDirectory> get_directories() const { return directories_; }
    void set_directories(std::vector<ManifestDirectory> dirs) { directories_ = dirs; }
    int ReadManifest(Manifest &manifest);

private:
    std::vector<ManifestDirectory> directories_;
};
```

and following simplified usage:

```
Manifest manifest;
manifest.ReadManifest(manifest);

for (std::vector<ManifestDirectory>::iterator it = manifest.get_directories().begin(); it != manifest.get_directories().end(); ++it) {
    // Do something
}
```

how to modify `get_directories()`, so it will not copy entire `directories_` and `it` in for loop will point the same directories_.begin()?

Right now iterator is incompatible is being thrown.

Comment: Return a reference `std::vector<ManifestDirectory>& get_directories() const { return directories_; }`

Comment: @RogerRowland Maybe I should make directories_ a pointer and modify get&set? Of course returning reference is working now - thanks.

Comment: What if I don't want to get `directories_` modified outside and only `ReadManifest()` will be able to do that and methods of `Manifest`?

Comment: Return constant reference. const std::vector<ManifestDirectory>& get_directories() const { return directories_; }

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the directories modified outside of `get_directories()`, return a const ref:

```
const std::vector<ManifestDirectory>& get_directories() const { return directories_; }
```

But make sure you create const iterators.